# jQuery UI Accordion disable tab

Tags: jquery, user-interface, accordion

How can i disable certain tabs in jQuery UI `accordion()`so user cannot click to open the content of the tab. Let's say i want to disabled the second tab in the below example.

http://jsfiddle.net/3JAkv/8/

Answer (score 3):

Maybe i'm wrong, 
but if i add the class "ui-state-disabled" to the desired header, the header / tab is no longer select-able.

I'm working with:
jquery-ui-1.10.3 and jquery-1.7.1

Comment: I use that too :-). Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

There is no bundled way to do this in 1.8.x.

In version 1.9 (beta release is available as of this writing) the `beforeActivate` event looks like you can handle and return `false` to prevent the activation from happening. Assuming you have set `.data('enabled', false)` on the header of the disabled section you could do something like the following in 1.9:

```
$('.ui-accordion').bind('accordionchangestart', function(event, ui) {
  if(ui.newHeader and !ui.newHeader.data('enabled')) {
    return false;
  }
  // fall through activation happens as normal
});
```

Comment: Thanks, But it's a little unclear to me. What is disabled_header. Can you work this in the jsfiddle link i provided above.

Comment: disabled_header is just a place holder for some indicator that you want that header disabled. It could be a class indicating state (`ui.newHeader.hasClass('disabled')`) or some state kept in Javascript variables. I just wanted to be _sure_ that you knew that return false meant `false` and not `"false"`.

Comment: Maybe you should consider a jQueryUI tabs widget instead since disabled tabs are a built in option. `$('#tabs').tabs('disable', tab_id_or_index)` and `$('#tabs').tabs('enable', tab_id_or_index)`

Comment: returning false does not stop the accordion from opening

Comment: I was probably reading the code for 1.9 which *does* allow the accordion changestart event to be cancelled: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.accordion.js#L678 1.8 does not: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1-8-stable/ui/jquery.ui.accordion.js#L408

Answer (score 0):

I'm pasting a JSFriddle with an example of a controlled navigation accordion. Meaning, user can't skip steps or navigate the accordion freely, but only by hard coded buttons that can be activated or placed by jQuery. Hope it helps.
https://jsfiddle.net/moriz/rvuwze6s/

Basically the js goes like this:

```
 $(function() {
     $("#accordion").accordion({
         disabled: true
     });
 });

 function operateAccordion(tabNumber) {
     $("#accordion").accordion("option", "active", tabNumber);
 }
```

And the buttons should go like this:

```
<a href="javascript:operateAccordion(1)">Next step</a>
```

Take into account accordion parts are numbered from 0 onwards. So this button can be used to go back or foward in the navigation.